# Angular. Передача значения в форму

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть метод ngOnInit(), в котором создаётся форма с дефолтными (пустыми) значениями

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup ( {
      name: new FormControl(defaultName, [Validators.required])
    })
  }
```

При нажатии в другом компоненте кнопки "редактировать" в компонент формы приходит уже определённое значение name, которое надо подставить вместо defaultName.
Как я понял это делается через ngOnChanges, но всё до чего я дошёл, это повторение кода ngOnInit, но уже со значением name

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup ( {
      name: new FormControl(name, [Validators.required])
    })
  }
```

Есть ли какой-то более оптимальный способ передачи параметра в уже существующую форму?

Comment: `this.form.get('name').setValue(name)`